# Consider $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that if $m<n$, then $m\neq n$ and $m+1\leq n$

Tags: solution-verification, natural-numbers

To solve this problem I will use this result proved before:

$$m,n\in\mathbb{N} \Rightarrow m+n\neq1.$$

By definition of order, there existes $p\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n=m+p\neq m$, using item above. Moreover, if $p=1$, we have $n=m+1$, but if $p>1$, then $n=m+p>m+1$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Apparently $0 \notin \Bbb N$ under your definition (be aware, it is more common to define $0 \in \Bbb N$ these days than not). What is "item (1)"? The thing you conclude from it does not follow directly from the result you quoted just above.  You say later that because $p > 1, m+p > m+1$. Have you already proven that?

Comment: I have erased "item (1)" and have proved the last inequality yet

Comment: But the "item above" *does not say* $m + p \ne m$. How do you get from "$m + n \ne 1$" to "$m + p \ne m$"?